# Compiler has different output than OCAJP preparation book Overloading methods

Tags: java, eclipse, overloading

I am preparing for the OCA Java SE 7 from a Enthuware question book and I get a different output when I compile in Eclipse running Java 1.7 compiler:

```
public class TestClass {
    void probe(int x) { System.out.println("In ...");} //1

    void probe(Integer x) { System.out.println("In Integer");} //2

    void probe(long x) { System.out.println("In long");} //3

    void probe(Long x) { System.out.println("In LONG");} //4

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer a = 4; new TestClass().probe(a); //5
        int b = 4; new TestClass().probe(b); //6
    }
}
```

The books output is: 
'In Integer and In long' and

the output in Eclipse shows 'In Integer and In...'.

Please help me verify which is the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: your output is correct.. could you re-check and tell if they are using long as the *lhs* in the book?

Comment: Book correct Options are : A D

A. In Integer and In long
B. In ... and In LONG, if //2 and //3 are commented out.
C. In Integer and In ..., if //4 is commented out.
D. It will not compile, if //1, //2, and //3 are commented out.
E. In LONG and In long, if //1 and //2 are commented out.

Was this in the old Java 6 specification?

Comment: I hope its not a typo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you are seeing is the correct behavior. Overloaded methods are resolved at compile time for the best datatype compatibility. Check with the jdk version for which the book is written for.

Comment: You are probably right...I think the book is using JDK 6 and has errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course your output is correct :) 
But I have done the same test yesterday and I have var args on the first line in my test:

```
void probe(int... x) { System.out.println("In ...");} //1
```

and not

```
void probe(int x) { System.out.println("In ...");} //1
```

So, in the case of using var args on the first line, the output of the Enthuware  test is correct.